# How to create a Dash Line with alternative different colour in esri ? Can we achieve this using SimpleLineSymbol?

Tags: javascript, gis, esri, esri-javascript-api

Example :  -------------- here alternative dash with red and yellow color.

Answer (score 0):

You can color lines according to specific conditions.

```
routeSymbols = {
          "Route 1": new SimpleLineSymbol().setColor(new Color([0,0,255,0.5])).setWidth(5),
          "Route 2": new SimpleLineSymbol().setColor(new Color([0,255,0,0.5])).setWidth(5),
          "Route 3": new SimpleLineSymbol().setColor(new Color([255,0,255,0.5])).setWidth(5)
        };

//Three different drawings can be made. 
map.graphics.add(routeResult.route.setSymbol(routeSymbols[routeResult.routeName]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want a single graphic with an alternative dashed line.
Your answer will work if I am having multiple graphics with type line.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking, one solid line with dashed line on top:

```
new CIMSymbol({
    data: {
        type: "CIMSymbolReference",
        symbol: {
            type: "CIMLineSymbol",
            symbolLayers: [
                {
                    type: "CIMSolidStroke",
                    effects: [
                        {
                            type: "CIMGeometricEffectDashes",
                            dashTemplate: [3.75, 3.75],
                            lineDashEnding: "HalfPattern",
                            offsetAlongLine: 0,
                        },
                    ],
                    enable: !0,
                    capStyle: "Butt",
                    joinStyle: "Round",
                    miterLimit: 10,
                    width: 1.6,
                    color: [253, 251, 83, 255],
                },
                { type: "CIMSolidStroke", enable: !0, capStyle: "Butt", joinStyle: "Round", miterLimit: 10, width: 1.6, color: [255, 165, 83, 255] },
            ],
        },
    },
});
```